# Update Trigger make multiple records update impossible

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have an update trigger, part of which is below that is causing the problem.

```
if ( (select [Account] from inserted) != (select [Account] from deleted))
    begin
    UPDATE Customers SET active_changed = CONVERT(varchar(10),GetDate(),102)
    FROM Customers ,INSERTED
    WHERE Customers .ID = INSERTED.ID
    end
```

If I do query like this

```
UPDATE Customers SET RepID= '111'  where repID = '222'
```

this does not work because the clause in the Update trigger fetches multiple records and it can not be executed.But if I do this

```
UPDATE Customers SET RepID = '111' where ID = '12345'
```

It works because ID is unique and fetches only one record.

Does someone has a remedy for this and a better way to rewrite my trigger?

What I am doing in the trigger is, if a a particular field in the record [Active] is changed (example: record made active or inactive), I am recording that date and put it in one of the field [active_changed]. This is just for audit purpose.

Apologies, I explained a bit wrong before, now fixed.

Any advice

Comment: What are You trying to achieve? You want trigger to update customers of all updated rows, or You want trigger not to do anything when update statement updates multiple rows?

Comment: First for all this trigger is working for me but it is also creating a problem. It does not allowed multiple rows to be update if I update on non-unique ID. I would like to fix that foremost.

Comment: I also fixed my explanation in the question a bit (last part), I hope this helps

Comment: Seems to me you don't quite understand what the effect is of
   (select [Account] from inserted) != (select [Account] from deleted)
=> you're trying to compare a recordset with a recordset here which isn't supported in TSQL.

Comment: @deroby, exactly. If you update 3 records, `will select [account] from inserted` pull 3 records or just 1? Since this is a trigger functionality, Does it work row-by-row basis or rows in bulk?

Comment: Triggers work in bulk (luckily). If you update 100 records, you'll find 100 records showing the 'before' state in [deleted], and 100 records showing the 'after' state in [inserted]. You can join these tables to find the actual changes but keep in mind that the UPDATE that raised the trigger might as well have been on the PK fields so joining both pseudo-tables might not always result in all 100 records again. (unless you do a FULL OUTER JOIN off course).
PS: tip : if you have an identity field in the table, you can use that to join both tables after an UPDATE as the field is 'untouchable'.

Comment: From that description my code is seriously flawed :) Need to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the requirement "I would like to register the date at which, it was changed. Account can either be 'active' or 'not-active'." I think you want this :

```
UPDATE Customers 
   SET active_changed = CONVERT(varchar(10),GetDate(),102)
  FROM Customers upd
  JOIN inserted i -- match by ID with new version
    ON i.ID = upd.ID
  JOIN deleted d -- match by ID with old version 
    ON d.ID = upd.ID
 WHERE i.Account <> d.Account -- when changed
```

This assumes the records 'never' get updated on the ID field. If you also want to catch the situation where an UPDATE can do that *and* you want such an operation also to set the active_changed field, you'll need something like below :

```
UPDATE Customers 
   SET active_changed = CONVERT(varchar(10),GetDate(),102)
  FROM Customers upd
  JOIN inserted i -- match by ID with new version
    ON i.ID = upd.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN deleted d -- match by ID with old version (might not have existed yet
               ON d.ID = upd.ID
 WHERE i.Account <> d.Account -- when changed
    OR d.ID IS NULL -- or when coming from different ID
```

Hope this helps.

PS: Why store the active_changed as a varchar instead of a datetime ?

Comment: Yes it does not have to be varchar but I just don't want the time to be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE A 
    SET A.active_changed = CONVERT(varchar(10),GetDate(),102)
FROM
    Customers A 
    INNER JOIN INSERTED B ON A.ID=B.ID
    INNER JOIN DELETED C ON A.ID=C.ID
WHERE
    B.Account <> C.Account
    -- below to cover nulls as above will evaluate to false if any of two fields is null
    OR
    B.Account IS NULL AND C.Account IS NOT NULL
    OR
    B.Account IS NOT NULL AND C.Account IS NULL
```

This works without need of IF clause, but to avoid involvement of Customers table at all when no records are going to be affected use below condition:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
    FROM INSERTED B INNER JOIN DELETED C ON B.ID=C.ID 
    WHERE B.Account <> C.Account 
        OR B.Account IS NULL AND C.Account IS NOT NULL 
        OR B.Account IS NOT NULL AND C.Account IS NULL)
BEGIN
    -- insert first sql
END
```

Comment: I'm still not quite sure on what the purpose of the trigger is (is it an INSTEAD OF TRIGGER or an AFTER ?), but I think your code might work for the purpose. 
That said : Use IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM...) rather than IF EXIST(SELECT NULL FROM..). It's a myth that the latter improves performance and if you start thinking about verifying if there is data by looking up 'undefined'... it could drive one crazy =)

Comment: If the `account` value has changed during the update process, I would like to register the date at which, it was changed. `Account` can either be 'active' or 'not-active'.